# node-js Upload Image to Google Cloud Platform

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, filereader

I am currently trying to upload an image from my Application to Google Cloud Storage.
I have already figures out how to upload the image, when I call my API built to upload with a file attached from postman everything works fine.

Where I am stuck is now uploading the file from within the App.

**Section 1: Working code**

API handling the uploading (this works with Postman)

```
[...]
router.post("/", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const myFile = req.file;
    const imageUrl = await uploadImage(myFile);
    res.status(200).json({
      message: "Upload was successful",
      data: imageUrl
    });
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
});
[...]
```

uploadImage function used in the code above:

```
const uploadImage = file =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const { originalname, buffer } = file;

    const removeWhitespaces = bucket.file(originalname.replace(/ /g, "_"));
    const blob = removeWhitespaces;
    blob.name += moment(Date()).format();
    console.log(blob);
    const blobStream = blob.createWriteStream({
      resumable: false
    });
    blobStream
      .on("finish", () => {
        const publicUrl = util.format(
          `https://storage.googleapis.com/${bucket.name}/${blob.name}`
        );
        resolve(publicUrl);
      })
      .on("error", () => {
        // eslint-disable-next-line prefer-promise-reject-errors
        reject(`Unable to upload image, something went wrong`);
      })
      .end(buffer);
  });
```

**Section2: Not working code.**

I try to pass an image stored in an object to a handler for the API. It seems that either in the upload or somewhere inbetween I am losing information for the image needed to get the upload successfull.

Upload of the image and adding it to the Product object

```
const handleUpload = ({ target }) => {
    const fileReader = new FileReader();

    fileReader.readAsDataURL(target.files[0]);
    fileReader.onload = e => {
      setValues({ ...values, image: e.target.result });
    };
  };
```

Post request to initiate the upload:

```
router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
const image = await uploadImage(req.body.image);

    const product = {
      description: req.body.description,
      image: image.data,
      tagline: req.body.tagline,
      title: req.body.title,
      responsiblePMs: req.body.assignedUsers,
      comments: req.body.comments,
      valueprop: req.body.valueprop,
      canvasTitles: req.body.canvasTitles
    };

   [... some mongoDB actions which then use Product]
```

Upload Image function (which should now again call the working post request):

```
const uploadImage = async image => {
  const data = new URLSearchParams();
  data.append("file", image);

  return fetch(baseURL, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
    body: data
  })
    .then(handleResponse)
    .catch(handleError);
};
```

**Section3: Error.**

```
TypeError: Cannot destructure property `originalname` of 'undefined' or 'null'.
    at Promise (/Users/stefanjanuschke/Development/viveyo-app/client/src/utils/GCB/processImage.js:19:38)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at uploadImage (/Users/stefanjanuschke/Development/viveyo-app/client/src/utils/GCB/processImage.js:18:3)
    at router.post (/Users/stefanjanuschke/Development/viveyo-app/client/api/routes/uploads.js:24:28)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/stefanjanuschke/Development/viveyo-app/client/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/stefanjanuschke/Development/viveyo-app/client/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/Users/stefanjanuschke/Development/viveyo-app/client/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/stefanjanuschke/Development/viveyo-app/client/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /Users/stefanjanuschke/Development/viveyo-app/client/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/Users/stefanjanuschke/Development/viveyo-app/client/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/stefanjanuschke/Development/viveyo-app/client/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at multerMiddleware (/Users/stefanjanuschke/Development/viveyo-app/client/node_modules/multer/lib/make-middleware.js:18:41)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/stefanjanuschke/Development/viveyo-app/client/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/stefanjanuschke/Development/viveyo-app/client/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /Users/stefanjanuschke/Development/viveyo-app/client/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/Users/stefanjanuschke/Development/viveyo-app/client/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
```

Comment: It looks like your issue with with this line: `const { originalname, buffer } = file;` are you sure that when you call `const imageUrl = await uploadImage(myFile);`  or `const image = await uploadImage(req.body.image);` that myFile has the property originalname: "some original name" because it seems to be null. It looks like your req.body.image most likely doesn't contain the property originalname

EDIT: realized you supplied two places where function is called.

Comment: The error is pretty self explanatory, you cannot destructure an undefined object. So start putting some try / catch blocks around the promise to see why promise  "orginalname" is empty.

Comment: I get that it is empty -> But why does the originalname (Filename) persist when uploading it into postman but not when reading it into the base64 ?